# Perl: How to read distinct value from text file and place in array?

Tags: oracle, perl

Friends...

(Question from newbie, sorry if this is too much in detailed but trying to provide all details to avoid any confusion)
I'm working on a script which search for all SID entries from Oracle tnsentry file and use distinct SID list to connect and query database for the result.

Oracle tnsentry file has got many duplicates with (SID = DB), so trying to use only distinct SID entry.

I can easily connect to single database by providing db name but we have 10 database so it gets bit tricky to

1. read tnsentry file (tnsfile.txt)
2. Search for db alias (SID = db1 , SID = db2 etc)
3. Store each db alias temporary into array
4. Use each alias for db connection in $dbConnect function

Mycode try:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $uNamePass = "user/password";
my @dbName;

#Uses username password and dbName to connect databsae
# e.g. user/password@db1

foreach my $item(@dbName) {    
  $dbConnect = &connect($uNamePass."@".$dbName);
  &getRows;
}
   exit($exitStatus);

#------------
sub readFile {

my $fName  = "c:\tnsentry.txt";
my $dbName;

# open file
if ( ! open (DAT, $fName) ) {
     &die;
  }

  # read file by each line
   while(<DAT>) {
      chomp;

  # if line begins with # sign, proceed to next
   next if /^\#/;

  # Next not able to figure out how to read each line and store distinct
  # DB name in an array to use for login in $dbConnect
  # I think I need to sepearte SID with /SID/ and search for string till it reaches ')'


}
```

Sample file (tnsfile.txt)

```
DB1=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB2=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db2))
  )

DB3=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB_ONE=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB_TWO=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db2 ))
  )
```

Comment: So you want array of tnsnames?

Comment: @mpapec ... yes, trying to store array of distinct tnsnames and use them for login.

Comment: To make distinct list, should address beside sid be considered?

Comment: @mpapec ... "SID = db1" or "SID = dbn" can appear multiple times in the file so don't want to connect same database multiple times and run query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure that an extraction of a unique list if SID names from tnsnames.ora (or whatever) is really a good idea, because different Oracle databases on different hosts might have same SID, here is what you have asked:

```
open(TNS,"tnsnames.ora")||die "ERROR: Can't open tnsnames.ora for read: $!";
while(<TNS>){$sids{$1}=0if/SID\s?=\s?(\w+)/}
print "$_\n" for(keys%sids);
```

or last 2 lines in a longer notation:

```
while (<TNS>)
{
   if (/SID\s?=\s?(\w+)/)
   {  $sids{$1} = 0 }
}

for (keys %sids)
{  print "$_\n" }
```

Comment: great idea and this really helped me in moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to be able to process your `tnsfile.txt` file to pull out the SID aliases.

You'll just have to `open` the file and duplicate this file processing to achieve your desired hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %sid;
my $name;

while (<DATA>) {
    $name = $1 if /^(\w+)=$/;
    $sid{$name} = $1 if /\(CONNECT_DATA\s*=\s*\(SID\s*=\s*(\w+)\s*\)/;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%sid;

__DATA__
DB1=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB2=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db2))
  )

DB3=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB_ONE=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB_TWO=
  (
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP))
   ...
   ...
  (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db2 ))
  )
```

Outputs:

```
{ DB1 => "db1", DB2 => "db2", DB3 => "db3", DB_ONE => "db1", DB_TWO => "db2" }
```

Comment: thank you for your comments but having duplicates in db name doesn't help exactly, also need to use each db name in loop to connect and query.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service.  I've broken down your problem and shown how to solve one piece.  Creating a loop for your data and validating the data structure should be an easy next step.

Comment: Never asked for perfect code ... just some similar examples or pointers.. thank you